# $(window).scrollTop highlighting elements

Tags: jquery, this, scrolltop, onscroll

I'm working on a project that is a series of posts on a page, and when the browser scrolls over, classes are added to that post only. I have a working concept here: http://jsfiddle.net/chdhmphry/V7jPU/

My issue is that this highlights all of the posts instead of just one. I tried to do a few work arounds, but non seem to allow me to just add the class to the post that fits the perameters(within 20px of the top of the window). I tried `$(this)`, hence why         `$(".post").ready(function () {` is a part of the code. What exactly am I doing wrong?

The jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(".post").ready(function () {
        post = $(".post", this).offset().top,
        opacity = post - 20;

        if (scroll >= opacity) {
            $(this).addClass("seventy");
        } else{
            $(this).removeClass("seventy");
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to each post, and changed how you got the value for post.  This has been edited to address your question in the comment: When the bottom of the post goes below the scrollTop then it will lose the seventy class.

```
$(".post").each(function () {
    var postTop = $(this).offset().top - 20,
        postBottom = $(this).height() + postTop - 100; // -100 is just to show it work, remove.

    if (scroll >= postTop &&
       scroll <= postBottom) {
        $(this).addClass("seventy");
    } else{
        $(this).removeClass("seventy");
        return false; // more efficient, but might not work.
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Is there anyway to remove the class once the code has passed? It wouldn't matter in this instance, but one of the ways I was thinking I could use it would be to use the title as a sticky, this would the info is readily available on longer posts.

Comment: Give me a sec and I will give it a try.